# android - disable Listview item click and re-enable it

Tags: android, listview, adapter

So I have the following code in the adapter:

```
@Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) 
    {
         GeneralItem item = super.getItem(position);
         boolean retVal = true;


            if (item != null)
            {
                if (currSection != some_condition)
                retVal = !(item.shouldBeDisabled());
            }
         return retVal;
     }


    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() 
    {
        return false;
    }
```

The question here: So if I disabled my item during initial binding, now I raise the event on the screen and need to enable them all no matter what. Do I rebind it all again after that action is performed?

for instance:

```
onCreate{

// create and bind to adapter
// this will disable items at certain positions 

}

onSomeClick{

I need the same listview with same items available for click no matter what the conditions of positions are, so I need them all enabled. What actions should I call on the adapter? 

}
```

The problem is I can have a really long listview too. It supposes to support 6000 items. So rebinding it certainly is not an option.

Thanks,

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What about having an instance variable on your adapter:

```
boolean ignoreDisabled = false;
```

Then in `areAllItemsEnabled`:

```
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return ignoreDisabled;
}
```

and then at the beginning of `isEnabled`:

```
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    if (areAllItemsEnabled()) {
        return true;
    }
     ... rest of your current isEnabled method ...
}
```

Then you can switch between the two modes by setting `ignoreDisabled` appropriately and calling `invalidate` on your `ListView`.

Note that the addition to `isEnabled` is probably unneeded; it just seems a bit more complete.

Comment: yes that's exactly how I solved it :) great answer thank you!